# How to do high dimensional integration in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, integration

I'm trying to integrate a high-dimensional integration:
∫∏pj(1-pj)f(pj)dpj,where j∈1,...,5. f(pj) is the distribution function of pj,pj~beta(0.3,0.7)
is there a R package for this kind of integration?

Comment: What are the bounds of the integrations ?

Comment: all pj belongs to [0,1]

Answer (score 1):

The integrand is "separable": it is the product of a function of `p1`, a function 
of `p2`, ..., a function of `p5`.

Moreover the bounds of integration are constant. Therefore the multiple integral 
of the product equals the product of the single integrals:

```
int_0^1 int_0^1 int_0^1 int_0^1 int_0^1 product( pi(1-pi)f(pi) ) dp1 dp2 dp3 dp4 dp5
 = product ( int_0^1 p(1-p)f(p) dp )
```

Thus, you can calculate the single integral `int_0^1 p(1-p)f(p) dp` and raise 
it to the power 5.

However, while this is mathematically true, this will "accumulate" the errors of the 
numerical integration. 
Then, numerically, it is better to use a multidimensional integral. To do so, 
use the `cubature` package.

But note that you calculate this integral in "closed form". Indeed, `f` is the 
pdf of the Beta distribution with parameters `a` and `b`. One has 
`f(p) = g_{a,b}(p) / beta(a,b)` with `int_0^1 g_{a,b}(p) dp = beta(a,b)`. 
It is easy to see that `p(1-p)g_{a,b}(p) = g_{a+1,b+1}(p)`. 
Therefore,

```
int_0^1 p(1-p)f(p) dp = 1/beta(a,b) int_0^1 g_{a+1,b+1}(p) dp 
 = beta(a+1,b+1) / beta(a,b)
```

Thus the result of your integral is `(beta(a+1,b+1)/beta(a,b))^5`. This can be simplified: `beta(a+1,b+1)/beta(a,b) = (ab)/((a+b)*(a+b+1))`.